# Params forwarded from Twilio different than API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Double checking something...

The params that are forwarded to my webhook are different than those documented (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message) as being sent through the REST API. I understand for some properties, but for some it's the same value with a different naming convention (**SmsStatus vs Status**).

Is this just the way it is or am I missing a way to set an api version or something.For initial test I'm relying on the Twilio console to set up the messaging webhook.

The ApiVersion property I'm getting says the version is

```
ApiVersion:2010-04-01.
```

Seems old.

**EDIT**

Webhooks get the Twiml APi which does differ from the Rest Api.

Comment: That is the latest version AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can see the [parameters that are sent to a webhook for an incoming message here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request#request-parameters).